# Convert Join to sub Query

Tags: eloquent

I have a join and i want to convert it to subQuery. Can someone please help me to do the same.
Here is the join with db table i have:

```
$jobId = 12;
$customerId = 15;
DB::table('user_access_customer_job')
                ->join('user_access_customer_job as parent_jobs', 'user_access_customer_job.parent_job_id', '=', 'parent_jobs.job_id')
                ->where('parent_jobs.job_id', '<>', $jobId)
                ->where('parent_jobs.customer_id', $customerId)
                ->where('user_access_customer_job.job_id', '<>', $jobId)
                ->whereRaw('parent_jobs.user_id <=> user_access_customer_job.user_id')
                ->whereRaw('parent_jobs.type = user_access_customer_job.type')
                ->select('parent_jobs.id')
                ->lists('id');
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite using a subquery?  I prefer the current version using joins.

Comment: What programming language is this? Please tag your request with it. It is obviously not SQL, which I guessed it to be from the `mysql` tag.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I want to rewrite using subquery because my table size is too large

Comment: ...subqueries probably won't help.  Rather, you need to index your current join query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I already have added index on the table columns

Comment: But have you run `EXPLAIN` on the raw query?  Are those indices being _used_?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I am not aware of EXPLAIN, can you please confirm how can i do that

Comment: @rahul anand: This is probably going to remain a private conversation between Tim and you, as long as you don't tag your request with the programming language you are using here. What you are showing is not MySQL, but some code in some language presumably independent from the DBMS. MySQL happens to be the DBMS you are using, but may not have much impact here. You don't want MySQL people to look at your request, but those other guys who know the language you are using.

Comment: @rahulanand if you add MySQL tag please post the query in sql format not in Laravel. Or you could remove MySQL tag. As per the explain part just run explain before your query...something like `EXPLAIN SELECT parent_jobs.id ....`